# Getting Error "CUDA binary kernel for this graphics card compute capability (8.6) not found"

Tags: gpu

I have a new NVIDIA RTX 3080 FE and I just started having issues where I'm unable to render via Cycles when in CUDA - GPU Support. When I first installed the card I didn't have any issues initially. I rendered an old project no problem. But I did a NVIDIA driver update to Geforce V 456.71 and since than I get this error - "CUDA binary kernel for this graphics card compute capability (8.6) not found."

I'm running Blender 2.83.8 Windows 64. I also downloaded Blender 2.90.1 thinking that might support the card, but that version simply crashes and I don't even get an error.

Has anyone else encountered this issue yet? Is this simply because the 3080 isn't supported for Cycles yet.

Comment: The Beta seems to be better :
https://builder.blender.org/download/ source : https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/jjz3ny/getting_this_message_with_my_3080_fe_cuda_binary/gafy7hh/

Comment: Curious if you ever got this working Ben?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official builds of Blender currently use CUDA Toolkit 10, but support for Ampere GPUs was added in CUDA Toolkit 11. If you're compiling Blender yourself, you can use CUDA Toolkit 11, but it's not officially supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps (if not I'll delete), but it's possible the update disabled CUDA for your GPU. Try checking in the NVIDIA control panel, and check if it's enabled (both globally and by program).

[image: CUDA]

Comment: I checked the NVIDIA control panel but CUDA seems to enabled. I'm a 3D modeler not a software engineer so trying to figure this out is a mess. It appears to be a Toolkit issue but I have no idea how to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Ben Dubs,
Try using the latest Blender 2.91. It surely is compatible with RTX 3080 gpu compute Cycles rendering. Even I faced this issue with Blender 2.83 LTS, but 2.91 will render everything smoothly.
Infact, you can just keep 2.91 for rendering purpose, if having trouble letting go 2.83.
Regards.